# JavaMail jar name causes JAF exception?

Tags: java, classpath, jakarta-mail

I'm running into an odd problem with a mail sending component in one of our projects.  Since we switched over to using Apache Ivy to manage build dependencies, we now deploy jars named `mail-1.4.4.jar` instead of the previous `mail.jar`.

With the versioned jar, we get a stacktrace (see below).  If I take that same jar and *manually* rename it to `mail.jar`, the mail is sent successfully.  It seems like some sort of classpath issue with JAF unable to find the mail component classes, but I'm stumped about how to resolve the root issue instead of a band-aid solution like configuring the build to rename the jar.

Failure stacktrace:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
        javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_522583802.1299253374905"
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1141)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at com.rbccm.core.util.MailUtil.sendMail(MailUtil.java:91)
        at com.rbccm.core.util.MailUtil.sendWithAttachment(MailUtil.java:59)
        at com.rbccm.core.util.MailUtil.sendWithAttachment(MailUtil.java:36)
        at com.rbccm.core.util.MailTask$Command$1.execute(MailTask.java:88)
        at com.rbccm.core.util.MailTask$Command$1.execute(MailTask.java:83)
        at com.rbccm.core.util.BatchTask.execute(BatchTask.java:31)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed;
        boundary="----=_Part_0_522583802.1299253374905"
        at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:877)
        at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:302)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1476)
        at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1772)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1099)
        ... 25 more
```

java -version output:

```
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a class path issue. The Java Activation Framework might be set up with a class path that includes `mail.jar`. That would explain why it works when you rename `mail-1.4.4.jar` to `mail.jar`.

Make sure your JAF and Java Mail API jars are compatible, then update the class path appropriately.

Comment: It is indeed a classpath issue.  Something else in the system was forcing a reference to mail.jar into the CLASSPATH variable.  I'm still confused as to why the component was failing to find the mail-1.4.4.jar, but that is an Ant classpath issue rather than a JavaMail issue so I will post another question.